# Spring Data JPA simple web Example with MySql and Maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am very new to JPA and Spring, so can you people give me a link or any working code of Spring Data JPA with MVC integration which have used Mysql and Maven.

Comment: i used Spring MVC and JPA to Google App Engine. can be more specific what you want?

Comment: I need simple MVC with Spring Data JPA example with MYSql and Maven .tht's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is SpringMVC(controller?) on top of what you asked, as you commented on Mustafa's answer:

> this is console based example, whereas I am looking for simple web based

This example might help you for Spring Data JPA:

> http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial

Or this for Spring MVC:

> http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial

Answer (score -1):

You can easily find hundreds of example. Here you can find a blogpost : http://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/jpa-basic-example-with-entitymanager-spring-and-maven/

Comment: Thanks Mustafa, but this is console based example whereas i am looking for simple web based example of Spring Data JPA with Mysql and Maven

Answer (score -1):

Try this [example](http://notetipsblog.com/NoteTipsBlog/articles/spring3/mvc/spring_mvc_form_maven_eclipse_jpa_tutorial_5.html) spring jpa with hibernate implementation, spring mvc and MySql,
or this blank project on [github](https://github.com/making/springmvc-jpa-blank).

Comment: Please include some information about why and how that helps. Also, please duplicate some of the information here in case the link dies.

Comment: Others won't be happy if the link you point to dies in the meantime.